# Unable to get serialize form data when submit from partial view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong.
I have a partial view in which there are customer details. Which is filled from parent view. Now i have to submit that form. 
But when I am going to do so it gets submit but getting model data null. Form data is not able to serialize.

Below is my partial view code:-

```
@model MobileBank.Models.CustomerDetails;

@{ 
    List<SelectListItem> list = ViewBag.Schemes;
    var str = string.Join(",",list.Where(p => ("," + Model.Schemes + ",").Contains("," + p.Text + ",")).OrderBy(i => Model.Schemes.Split(',').ToList().IndexOf(i.Text)).ToList().Select(s => s.Text));

}

<div class="box-body" style="margin-top: 2%;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreatePIN", "RegisterCustomer", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "customerDetailForm" }))
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_ShowMessages");
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fincif)
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fincif, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "CIF" })*@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fincif, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled ="disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "CIF", style= "margin-bottom:8px;" } })
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "Name", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })*@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "Name" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, new { id = "DOB", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })*@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "DOB" } })
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo)
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "MobileNo" })*@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "MobileNo" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1)
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address1, new { id = "Address1", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })*@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "Address1" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Schemes)
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @if (Model.Schemes != null)
                {
                    @*@Html.TextBox("Schemes",str,new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "Schemes" })*@
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => str, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "Schemes" } })

                }
                else
                {
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Schemes, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "Schemes" })*@
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Schemes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "Schemes" } })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row divMargin">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
                <button type="submit" id="btnCreatePin" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 2%;">Create PIN</button>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:return GoBack();" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    //$('#customerData').html(response);
                    //$('#crtPIN').show();
                    HideWait();
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    toastr.error('Error while processing your request');
                    HideWait();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Method to which I want to post form data as below:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[TypeFilter(typeof(Authorize))]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreatePassword(CustomerDetails model)
{
    try
    {
       //Work to do..
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CatchError(ex);
    }
    return View();
}
```

In Below Image, when I enter cif number and mobile number and submit, below listing is fetch. which is the form in partial view. That I need to submit on creating in submit button click. But I am getting no data 
[image]

Comment: Disabled stuff is not sent. Add hidden fields with the values.

Comment: Or don't make your form reliant on those values at all. It is bad practice in my thinking, because you're basically letting the customer to edit the data with minimal editing of the page sent to him, save the data somewhere on the server and only rely on the disabled stuff to display it to the customer.

Comment: Thanks mishan , I will remove disable as these fields I have to keep only read-only. This data is just to verify, I did not want user to edit it.  Should i go with textbox for insted of editor for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your inputs are disabled. Either enable them or add another hidden input that is not disabled with the same value and it will send.

Example for CIF:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.fincif, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled ="disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "CIF", style= "margin-bottom:8px;" } })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.fincif)
```

Comment: Thankyou very much mishan , yes it work. Can you suggest me some best practice to follow in case of partial view and form submit case.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know it helped. It's only my personal preference, but I'd make it so that the data in the read only fields are not needed at all (and thus can be displayed or not dispayed based on preference). As fot the way to make it, I'm not the best to ask, but there was software engineering and programming stack exchange aside from stack overflow, maybe it's best you ask there?